# Python: Delete a character from a string

Tags: python, string

I want to delete i.e. character number 5 in a string. So I did:

del line[5]

and got:
TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion

So no I wonder whether there is a different efficient solution to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python, so you can't change them in-place.

But of course you can assign a combination of string slices back to the same identifier:

```
mystr = mystr[:5] + mystr[6:]
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sence. Imagine if your answer could get integrated into the python error message. And image if that error message was some kind of a community wiki so I could integrate it myself. I can accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @David: The immutability of certain basic Python types (especially [strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and [tuples](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)) is something that baffles many newcomers to the language, but which makes a lot of sense and is a fundamental Python concept. After all, you don't expect to be able to change integer values in-place, either. So this is considered basic Python knowledge; the error message is clear enough for my taste.

Comment: I agree that it is clear, one cannot write everything in error message. But just imagine if all error messages contained a web link to a wiki page where all information/solutions about the problem could be included.

Answer (score 1):

I use a function similar to :

```
def delstring(mystring, indexes):
  return ''.join([let for ind, let in enumerate(mystring) if ind not in indexes])
```

*indexes* should be an iterable (list, tuple..)

Answer (score 1):

bytearray is a type which can be changed in place. And if you are using Python2.x, it can very easily convert to default str type: bytes.

```
b=bytearray(s)
del b[5]
s=str(b)
```